# Criar constantes corretamente com mean.js (node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, mongoose

Estou começando a estudar o mean.js e fiquei em dúvida quando a melhor forma de criar minhas constantes de aplicação. Tenho necessidade de armazenar algumas constantes no projeto para serem acessíveis em várias partes do código.

Pesquisando, não encontrei nada referente à constantes na documentação do próprio mean.js... Na web, encontrei essas referências aqui mesmo no stackoverflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881665/how-to-define-a-constant-and-access-it-everywhere-in-nodejs

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595509/how-do-you-share-constants-in-nodejs-modules

Especificamente no segundo link achei a resposta do Dominic Barnes bem elegante, mas no caso específico do mean.js há ainda uma abstração de módulos a considerar (o mongoose).

Como eu poderia criar minhas constantes sem interferir o funcionamento do mongoose (e sem ficar feio, de preferencia =) )

Obs: uma coisa que eu gostaria é que cada arquivo de módulos mantivesse suas p´roprias constantes, assim um model de Carros por exemplo, teria a constante

Carros.CARRO_DE_PASSEIO

Que poderia ter uma string, objeto etc (Já me contentaria bem com uma string hehe). Algo mais ou menos assim...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No NodeJS existe `global` que é uma variável global. Da mesma maneira que `window` no javascript no browser.

Assim é possivel adicionar propriedades a `global` e usá-las onde se quiser. Convém no entanto usar por exemplo `global.minhasConstantes = {};` e nesse objeto adicionar chave-valor para cada constante, e não adicionar novas constantes diretamente `global.constanteA = 'foo'; global.constanteB = 'bar';` por uma questão de boa prática.

No entanto o que eu costumo fazer é defenir as variáveis quando chamo os módulos. Exemplos:

no index.js

```
var modulo = require('modulo')(minhaConstante);
```

e no módulo:

```
module.exports = function(k){
    return function(){
       // aqui fica o códigoque precisa da constante "k" que é passada para o escopo da função
    }
}
```

ou somente:

```
module.exports = function(k, outroParametro){
   // aqui fica o códigoque precisa da constante "k" que é passada para o escopo da função
}
```

Comment: Aí que está... com mongoose eu não uso o module.exports, e sim mongoose.model('MeuModel', MeuModelSchema); (Claro que defini o MeuModelSchema antes). Eu posso, dentro desse arquivo de model exportar as globals também? eles serão lidos mesmo se eu não fizer require do model? Postei essas perguntas, mas vou fazer os testes eu mesmo mais tarde, só que no momento estou meio travado aqui.

Comment: @RômuloO.Torres exportanto para `global` vai estar acessível. Não é a melhor prática mas é possivel. Talvez o melhor mesmo é passar dentro do `MeuModelSchema`. Se colocar um exemplo do seu código/estrutura é mais fácil ajudar.

Comment: Vou colocar como exemplo o código do próprio mean... veja esse exemplo de model exportado pelo mongoose:
https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/app/models/article.server.model.js

Agora imagine que eu vá ate o controlador de Articles e queira usar uma constante... gostaria que fosse possível por exemplo ter uma constante definida como Articles.ARTIGO_A, que tivesse sido definida no meu model... enfim é mais ou menos isso