# Utilizar require() (ou outro método) no NodeJS como no PHP

Tags: php, node.js, require, import

#### No PHP

Suponhamos que eu tenha um arquivo de constantes, em um diretório root, chamado ***const.php***:

```
define('CONST_1', BASE_CONST_1 || 'Value 1');
define('CONST_2', 'Value 2');
define('CONST_3', 'Value 3');
```

E um outro arquivo, no mesmo diretório, chamado ***index.php***:

```
define('BASE_CONST_1', 'Valor que veio do índice';

require_once 'const.php';

echo CONST_1; // Iria aparecer na tela do usuário `Valor que veio do índice`.
```

Enfatize acima o que aconteceu:

- Definimos no arquivo ***index.php*** uma constante, que foi passada para o arquivo ***const.php*** e que foi usada para definir outra constante com base no seu valor (`CONST_1`).
- Chamamos a constante `CONST_1` de volta para o arquivo ***index.php***, sem nenhum tipo de exportação no arquivo de sua origem.

> Obviamente não há nenhuma lógica em fazer exatamente como fiz acima, o meu objetivo foi só mostrar o que posso fazer no PHP.

#### No NodeJS

Em NodeJS, eu desconheço uma forma de fazer isso, tendo em vista que:

- Variáveis e constantes não são passadas para o arquivo que importamos (*da mesma forma como, no exemplo de PHP, a constante `BASE_CONST_1` foi passada para o arquivo **const.php**.*

#### A pergunta

Eu posso fazer, em NodeJS, o mesmo que fiz com o PHP (no exemplo acima), sem ter que criar funções e passar parâmetros nelas?

Comment: **Relacionado**: [Criar constantes corretamente com mean.js (node js)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47271) ?

Comment: Não. Esse não é o assunto da pergunta. Só dei o exemplo das constantes para explicar melhor a pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Node.js utiliza módulos que você pode importar. Por exemplo:

```
// modulo.js
module.exports = {
   'funcao' : function() { return 'função executada'; },
   'propriedade' : 10
}

// principal.js
const meuModulo = require('./modulo');
console.log(meuModulo.funcao());
console.log(meuModulo.propriedade);
```

Comment: Yap. Até aí eu consegui. O problema é quando tenho um arquivo que não é necessariamente um módulo. O único jeito de se importar um arquivo JavaScript no contexto do Node é pelo `module.exports` e `require()` (considerando o arquivo como módulo)? Não gosto muito da ideia de encapsular todo o meu arquivo em uma função só para executá-lo em outros.

Comment: Essa é a maneira correta e recomendada. Sempre existe a opção de ler o arquivo do disco usando a biblioteca padrão do node pra isso, e dar um eval nesse arquivo. Com uma operação parecida você também pode reescrever o arquivo e transformá-lo num módulo, e a partir daí usar o require.